# @PostLoad in super class

Tags: java, jpa

I have several Entity classes. Now I want to use @PostLoad in every entity. The function code is for every entity the same. So I made a super class (public abstract class AbstractModel {..}) which contain the @PostLoad method. Now is it possible to do this? In a quick test the method is not executed but the method is executed placed in the entity... Maybe someone has a workaround for this?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Parent implements Serializable
{

    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad()
    {
        System.out.println("postLoad called!");
    }


}
```

My entity class who extends from Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "albums") //de naam van de tabel wordt 'albums'
public class Album extends Parent implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id") //de naam van de kolom wordt 'id'
    private Long id;

...
}
```

And the error when I'm running it:

> Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services -
>   2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
>   Exception Description: An exception
>   was thrown while searching for
>   persistence archives with ClassLoader:
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
>
> Internal Exception:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services -
>   2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>
> Exception Description: Predeployment
>   of PersistenceUnit [JPA_TestPU]
>   failed.
>
> Internal Exception: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services -
>   2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
>   Exception Description: Entity class
>   [class jpatest.Album] has no primary
>   key specified. It should define either
>   an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If
>   you have defined PK using any of these
>   annotations then make sure that you do
>   not have mixed access-type (both
>   fields and properties annotated) in
>   your entity class hierarchy.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, you HAVE annotated the abstract parent class @Entity or @MappedSuperclass?

Comment: If you posted your code this would be much easier

Comment: Now I marked it as @MappedSuperclass butnow it complains about their is no primary key in the sub class (sub class is the entity and super class is the mappedsuperclass). In the sub class their is a primary key.

Comment: @Stijn please, please, please post the code? (why do I have to beg for this?)

Comment: I posted it :) can you figure it out?

Comment: Reading the error message, are you mixing field and method annotations? (note that the @PostLoad annotation is not a problem here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least "Java Persistence with JPA" says that this should work when applied to a mapped super class (mark AbstractModel with @MappedSuperClass).

Comment: I did, but in the superclass I need to define an @Id which I don't want to do... Because in the sub classes (the entities) I defined already keys. But I shall copy/paste the @PostLoad in every Entity then.

Comment: That's weird, we use @MappedSuperClasses with no @Id's (the extending classes naturally have @Id's), and we've never encountered problems with this (although we're using Hibernate as the JPA-implementation, I have no experience with EclipseLink). As @GeneratedValue-strategies we use GenerationType.IDENTITY (the id's in the database are of PostgreSQL Serial-type), but I don't think that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are unintentionally switching access types and EclipseLink is ignoring the field annotations.  As it is the @PostLoad causing this I recommend filing a bug.
If you are using JPA 2.0 you can specify the access type on the Album directly or if using JPA 1.0 simply annotate for property access:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "albums") //de naam van de tabel wordt 'albums'
public class Album extends Parent implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id") //de naam van de kolom wordt 'id'
    public Long getId(){
        ...
    }

    public Long setId(Long id){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did your AbstractModel is mapped with `@MappedSuperclass` ?