# Adding PostLoad Annotation to a SuperClass in Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, annotations, morphia

I have a superclass and inherited classes which are morphia entities. 
I want to add a `@PostLoad` function to run for all inherited entities. Can I do this?

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109818/postload-in-super-class) question which is for, I guess, SQL databases. I want to make sure if that will also work with morphia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own that parent class, you can just annotate the method on the parent class and Morphia should take care of the rest.